# Spring - Data persisted by JdbcTemplate unable to be seen by JpaRepository

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-boot, transactions, spring-data-jpa

I am building a Spring Boot application which requires the need for persistence via JDBC and selecting/reading via JPA/Hibernate. I have implemented both of these types of operations using Spring's JdbcTemplate and Spring Data's JpaRepository.

After I persist using JdbcTemplate I am unable to see the data via JpaRepository even though they share the same datasource. I am able to read the data if I use JdbcTemplate.

**NOTE:** I am using two data sources. One is configured in another class without the @Primary annotation using its own entity manager factory and transaction manager, which is why I've needed to explicitly define it below using Spring Boot's default bean terminology "transactionManager" and "entityManagerFactory".

The following is my embedded database configuration for the primary beans:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.repository"})
public class H2DataSourceConfiguration {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(H2DataSourceConfiguration.class);

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .setName("dataSource")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, DataSource dataSource) { 
        return builder
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .packages("com.my.domain", "org.springframework.data.jpa.convert.threeten")
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
        return jpaTransactionManager;
    }
}
```

The persistence happens in a different transaction to the reading of the data, however they share the same service.
Both operations happen within the @Transactional annotation. Both repository beans are specified in the same service and also contain the @Transactional annotation. The service looks as follows:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private MyJpaRepository myJpaRepository;

    @Autowired
    private MyJdbcRepository myJdbcRepository;

    ...
}
```

MyJdbcRepositoryImpl.java:

```
@Repository
@Transactional(propagation = Propagataion.MANDATORY)
public class MyJdbcRepositoryImpl implements MyJdbcRepository {

    @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

   // methods within here all use jdbcTemplate.query(...)
}
```

MyJpaRepository.java:

```
@Repository
@Transactional(propagation = Propagataion.MANDATORY)
public interface AcquisitionJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<AcquisitionEntity, Long> {

}
```

Is it at all possible that the jdbctemplate calls are saving to a different h2 database?

Comment: I'd turn on logging in the hibernate to show the SQL and compare the hibernate generated SQL that's running from the JPA repository with your manually written JDBC template code.

Can you post your persistence and query code as well.

Fascinated to know why you are persisting with manual JDBC.

Comment: you have not specified any vendoradapter for your LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean. may be that is the cause

Comment: The fact that you cannot read it probably means you haven't committed it or have 2 transactions. You cannot read uncommitted data from another transaction. Also if you are using Spring Boot why all the manual configuration?

Comment: Why do you create JpaTransactionManager manually? It looks like you have two independent transactions.

Comment: @PaulNUK Persisting with JDBC because our volume level requires its speed. Reading with JPA as we need to stream some results and paginate others.

Comment: @pvpkiran Spring Boot automagically configures Hibernate as the Vendor Adapter via the builder passed in to the entityManagerFactory.

Comment: @AndriySlobodyanyk JpaTransactionManager is supposed to support any jdbcTemplate transactions as well as Spring Data Jpa transactions under the hood.

Comment: @wild_nothing Well, please add some code from MyJdbcRepository and let's dig into http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#tx-resource-synchronization. Do you use JdbcTemplate or DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource)?

Comment: @AndriySlobodyanyk Added the code. I'm using jdbcTemplate and not DataSourceUtils. Should I be?

Comment: @M.Deinum Two transactions are being performed. The first one persists and the second one is called as part of a web service endpoint.

Comment: @wild_nothing No, you shouldn't. That's fine with jdbcTemplate. But I'm still afraid of creating two transactional manager. BTW, why JpaTransactionalManager is marked with @@Primary? Do you have another one? And repositories should not have @@Transactional, it's service responsibility. Well, my proposals are quite simple -- remove @@Transactional from repositories and remove manual creation of Transactional Manager.

Comment: @AndriySlobodyanyk Yes, I have another one unfortunately. There are two datasources. This is the main one so I've marked it with @@Primary so that I don't need to explicitly define it each time I use @@Transactional. This is the default one Spring Boot uses for all its auto configuration. The other data source has its own defined entity manager and transaction manager.

Comment: Still stuck on this. It makes no sense why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above configuration is correct!

The problem was that the JdbcTemplate calls had the schema owner as a prefix.
For example:

```
select * from I_AM_SCHEMA.KILL_ME
```

However, I had both the @Entity annotation and the @Table annotation on the entity object and only specified the table name!
Example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "KILL_ME")
```

So, we were writing to one table with JdbcTemplate but reading from a completely different other table via JPA/Hibernate due to us missing the prefix.

The correct fix was to prefix the entity name in the @Entity annotation:

```
@Entity("I_AM_SCHEMA.KILL_ME")
```

DONE!